# respondsToSelector to know which ios version user is running

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm new to programming and had a question.  As newer API comes out, like things in iOS 5 for example, do you need to have two ways of doing something (pre ios5 and ios5)?  Like

```
if ([respondsToSelector: (some ios 5 method)]) {
   // use iOS 5 methods
}
else {
   // use pre ios 5 methods
}
```

Sorry if this is a noob question, it's just not something that was really covered in the classes I've taken so far.  Thanks.

Comment: Only if you want to continue supporting any previous versions. If you drop support for older versions, you can use iOS 5 APIs unconditionally. (Of course, you have to weigh this against how many of your users you'll upset because they haven't upgraded to 5 or have devices that can't run it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a perfectly acceptable method to check for available APIs.

Comment: even better, this is the *recommended* way of checking for available APIs.